# Request header add script tag in Referer , how to validate in asp.net webfroms

Tags: asp.net, http, request, header

The value of the Referer HTTP header is copied into the value of an HTML tag attribute which is encapsulated in double quotation marks. The payload qwasde">alert(1)qweae was submitted in the Referer HTTP header. This input was echoed unmodified in the application's response.

This proof-of-concept attack demonstrates that it is possible to inject arbitrary JavaScript into the application's response.

in request object inject  Referer: q6tfd">alert(1)kgt2v

when page load alert display ..
how to validate Referer in asp.net

how to avoid in asp.net ?

Comment: Can you provide any codd you have for this?  It is very hard to understand what you are asking without context oor code.

Comment: `code:  Referer: q6tfd"><script>alert(1)</script>kgt2v `
if some one add this in request header,  it give a alert on page lode